# Ошибка при создании кнопки python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Всем привет. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку появлялись новые кнопки. Выдает ошибку:

> kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView object at 0x00000285C29F3D68>, it already has a parent

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так и как исправить.

Код .py:

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

Window.size = (240, 426)

screen = Screen()

scroll = ScrollView(
            size_hint=(0.5, 0.7),
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        )

class Container(GridLayout):

    def add_group(self):

        self.grid = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=None)
        self.grid.bind(minimum_height=self.grid.setter("height"))
        button = Button(
            text="Создать группу",
            size_hint_y=None,
            height=dp(200),
            on_release=self.new_group,
        )
        screen.add_widget(scroll)
        self.grid.add_widget(button)
        scroll.add_widget(self.grid)
        return screen

    def new_group(self, *args):
        self.grid.add_widget(
            Button(text="Новая группа", size_hint_y=None, height=dp(100))
        )

class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testApp().run()
```

Код .kv:

```
<Container>
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}
    grid: grid
    orientation: 'vertical'
    rows: 3

    GridLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}
        id: grid

        Button:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}
            text: 'Add group'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(100)
            on_release:
                root.add_group()
```

Comment: А что в итоге должно получиться?

Comment: В итоге при каждом нажатии на кнопку на лэйауте должны появляться новые кнопки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите:

- `Container` это компоновщик `GridLayout`, а добавляете вы виджеты на созданный в нем `self.grid`, но сам `self.grid` не добавлен в `Container` (`self.add_widget(self.grid)`).
- Перенес создание `self.grid` и добавление в конструктор, чтобы оно только один раз было выполнено для виджета
- Что-делать с `screen` и `scroll` не знаю, поэтому убрал их

Попробуйте:

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


Window.size = (240, 426)


class Container(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.grid = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=None)
        self.grid.bind(minimum_height=self.grid.setter("height"))

        self.add_widget(self.grid)

    def add_group(self):
        button = Button(
            text="Создать группу",
            size_hint_y=None,
            height=dp(200),
            on_release=self.new_group,
        )
        self.grid.add_widget(button)

    def new_group(self, *args):
        self.grid.add_widget(
            Button(text="Новая группа", size_hint_y=None, height=dp(100))
        )

class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testApp().run()
```